# Positioning table header in div

Tags: html, css, tabular

[See my fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/6yU6N/41/)

I am trying to position the header inside the div like so:

[image]

Not having much luck. What's going on?  How do position within the table row header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That div.headerContainer is not valid markup so the browser will try to correct it. Rather style the th 's and add classes for first and last. Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/fSNqB/). Another option would be to use an appropriately sized background image and apply it to the parent div (.geniusPicks)

HTH! :)